# Finding the extra space at the end of a line in Word with Python

Tags: python, ms-word

I am working on a project, but there are several things that I have had trouble finding documentation for. In Microsoft word, when you type out a sentence, if a word goes past the set margins it drops down to the next line (I know this is common knowledge, but it's relevant).
Margins:

```
|                               |
|Is this a good margin or is----|
|finding a better margin even---| 
|possible if we make minor------|
|adjustments.-------------------|
```

The space I've marked with the hyphens is what I am trying to find. I could always make an estimate by finding the characters in a line, but I want the exact amount of blank space left over.
So for line 1 with margins of x how much of the line is occupied by the section of characters?

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it does go to the next line -- it's called text wrapping.

Comment: https://www.electricteacher.com/images/embed-image-in-text.gif

Comment: That's with text wrapping, see the blank space between the margin and last character of each line, that's what I am trying to find

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that space will change based on the width of your screen. It's not just "how many spaces are left", you'd need to know the window size as well.

Comment: It's for printing purposes so the margins would be like they are in word, so in inches

Comment: The standard margins are about 1 inch both sides with the page being 8.5 inches wide, so the max line length is 6.5 inches

Comment: With a Word file there is no easy way to find this out. Word does not trigger line wrapping by adding spaces. And the blank space on the right doesn't equate to an integral number of spaces anyway. There only *appear* to be an integral number of spaces in the special case of a fixed-width font and ragged-right justification. There are generally ways to discover the width in pixels of a stretch of text in a given font and point size (also taking boldface and italics into account). Whatever the renderer, they are complex and finicky. I'm not sure that the Word COM API even makes them visible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string's will have a '|' at the end of them, the below code should work. Tell me if the `|` will not always be there I'll remove my post.

```
x = "                               "[::-1]
spaces = 0
for i in x:
    if i == ' ':spaces += 1
    else:break
```

**output**

```
31
```

Note: len(string) returns 31

Comment: I thought about doing a count like that too, but wouldn't that change depending on kerning/font size? I need the actual length, like the physical length between the end of the characters and the margin

Comment: And the | was just to show visualize the margin, my fault

Comment: @Jack Hulse, to your last comment, are you saying that it would be best to not take the | in to account?

Comment: There has to be a way of working out what the actual space length would be, then calculate how many spaces per line, then multiply by the actual space length in inches

Comment: Yes ignore the |

Comment: This is a better example

Comment: https://www.electricteacher.com/images/embed-image-in-text.gif

Comment: You want to count the amount of spaces after the first paragraph? In that case if you take that text and put it into your editor it will take it as the same amount of spaces shown in the websites text.

Comment: Maybe I should just explain what it is I am trying to accomplish. A few months ago, I was working with a word document and just fooling around, it was a pretty large document. Anyway, I made some super small changes to the kerning/font size and noticed that sometimes increasing the font by a super small amount actually reduced the total length of the document

Comment: The reason was in a big document, there's a lot of word spillage from text wrapping, and you get extra physical blank space

Comment: So my reasoning is that if you say want your document to have a font between 11.5 to 12 with a kerning between x - y, what is the minimal amount of blank space left over per line, or now that I am typing this I realize a better solution

Comment: Which would be just to count how many overall lines there are in the document

Comment: So the algorithm would work like this: Take the users min max range for font size and kerning, run through a for loop for the font size with another for loop with the kerning size, and find the most optimized combination to reduce paper use

Comment: On small documents this effect is almost nil, but on large documents very small changes can cascade across the document.